# Memory allocation of character array in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter\n";
    char ch[0];
    cin>>ch;
    cout<<sizeof ch;
    cout<<sizeof &ch;
    cout<<"\n You entered \n"<<ch<<"\n";    
    return 0;
}
```

I use g++ compiler to compile the C++ program. What is the difference in memory allocation of `char ch` and `char ch[0]`. `ch` can accept one character but `ch[0]` can accept many character(I put in qqqqqqqq). Why? Also why does `sizeof ch` return 0 whereas `sizeof &ch` gives 4, yet `ch` accepts more than four characters?

Comment: Standard C++ does not allow zero size automatic storage arrays. So you must be using a compiler extension.

Comment: And even then... How/why do you expect a zero-sized array to hold anything?

Comment: I did it just to understand the memory allocation.Instead of ch[0] if i give ch[1],then also many characters can be given.And i use the standars g++ compiler in ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this line by line:

```
char ch[0];
```

declares a zero-length array of characters. As mentioned in the comments, C++ standards don't actually allow this, but g++ might.

```
cin >> ch;
```

puts whatever's read in into the zero-length array. Since `cin` doesn't know the length of your array (it decays into a `char *` when it gets passed to the stream), it writes as much as it feels, which means it can store more than zero characters.

```
cout << sizeof ch;
```

outputs the size (ie. total space used in bytes) of the array, which is zero, as mentioned earlier.

```
cout << sizeof &ch;
```

outputs the size of the *address* of the array, which is 4 bytes on your architecture, since it's just a pointer.

```
cout << "You entered\n" << ch << "\n";
```

outputs whatever was stored into the array, which isn't well-defined, because, as I mentioned, zero-length arrays are not standard C++. Further, since `cout` just writes memory until it encounters a null byte (`\0`), it writes as much as you stored, since again, `cout` doesn't care whether you delcared `ch` with size `0` or size `413`.

Answer (score 1):

> > What is the difference in memory allocation of char ch and char ch[0].

The difference is in how much the compiler is going to protected you from yourself.  An array is just a sequential block of memory, C++ has not array out of bounds exceptions, and doesn't check array bounds before writing.  By using

```
char ch[0];
```

you have told the C++ compiler you will be responsible for bounds checking.  This is a buffer overflow (remember those).  When you assign something like 'qqqq' to `ch[0]` you have overwritten some other piece of memory that belongs to some other variable, function or program.  Try running the program below if you need a better understanding.

```
// Note that I'm setting arr[10], which in Java (or any other modern language) would
// be an array out of bound exception
// I haven't run this program, but you're most likely to get 'a' printed
// to standard out
char arr[10], achar;
arr[10] = 'a';
cout << achar;
```

Comment: But in the above code when i gave 
    arr[14] = 'a'
it prints some junk values instead of aborted core dumped error